# Unable to scroll into view of an element in iOS with Appium & Webdriverio

Tags: test-automation-framework, appium, javascript, mobile-automation, mobile-testing

i'm trying to scroll into an element but the the current code scrolls all the way to the bottom of the page, i have inserted the element name within the code but it doesn't seem to work.

`const eatenMeal = $$('~meal1CardAddRecipeButton')`

`await driver.execute('mobile: scroll', { element: eatenMeal, direction: "down" });`

Any advice appreciated